# git cherry pick failed because of permissions missing

Tags: linux, git

I have a repository that contains some files and directories owned by root instead of a regular user on Linux (Debian).
When those files are changed between commits (on the same or different branch ) and i checkout between those commits it fails because of permissions.

`error: unable to unlink old 'fileownedbyroot' (Permission denied)`

It is usually not an issue because I just need to chmod o+w -R on parent directories of those files and then git checkout --  to have the checkout correctly done. 
Just after that, I change the permissions back to their original values (chmod o-w -R). This works fine.

However, I have the same issue when I do a cherry-pick but the difference is that there is no message saying that the cherry pick failed.

`git status` gives :

```
    Changes not staged for commit:
    (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file1
    modified:   file2
    .. and so on`
```

for all files **not owned** by root and there is no more status of the files owned by root. Besides, there is nothing that indicates I am still cherry-picking ( as when it fails because of conflicts ).

What solution do I have then? Manually modify the files owned by root and apply the commit? Apply the cherry pick again in this situation? I just want to be sure that my repo would remain clean.

My local git version is 2.1.4

Thanks

Comment: Why not clone the whole repository into a location that you can freely work on?

Comment: It's what i did actually.

Comment: How did these files end up being owned by root?

Comment: Files owned by root are deployed to a target that is an embedded linux which has only one root user, otherwise they would be owned by "nobody". The repo is on the host machine and the deployment script change the permissions for those files and let them as-is in the repo.Those files are mostly software config files, translations, design...

Comment: I think this may be the root (no pun intended) of your problem - you're having to do a lot of dancing to work around the fact that you're modifying owners/permissions of files tracked by Git. Have you considered, for example, leaving the original files alone, and having your script create untracked copies?

Comment: Exactly, i am dancing a lot ;) and as a workaround, the deployment script could indeed be modified to gives back original permissions to the files. However the question still stands i think.